# grant privileges to role

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-grant

The question is:

Create a "UnivUser" role, and give this role the privileges of select, update, insert, delete, and execute pl / sql packages and sequences. This user will not be able to do anything other than these actions, to help you, you can search in the dialog of SqlDevelopp privileges for a user.

the execute, select and delete work for me using these commands:

```
GRANT select_catalog_role to UnivUser
GRANT execute_catalog_role to UnivUser
GRANT delete_catalog_role to UnivUser
```

but for `insert` and `update` it does not work for me I don't know how to do it or maybe I did not understand the question.

Comment: If by *"it does not work for me"* you mean that you tried `grant insert to univuser` and you got the error *ORA-01924: role 'INSERT' not granted or does not exist*, then that would be because you have to grant insert ON some table. But you forgot to mention what you tried or what problem you hit so that would be a guess.

Comment: I want to give the user permission to insert on **all** the tables and not on a specific table I do not know if that's what he asks in the question.

Comment: There is no generic "insert" (or "update" or "delete" etc) privilege. Any user can automatically do all of those things with his/her own tables. Perhaps the question refers to some SQL Developer feature, but I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: no i don't think they can modify on tables automatically, we need to give them privilege with `grant`.. even the connexion with `grant connect to user_name`
thank you so much .

Comment: You may not think so, but all the same you don't need any additional privileges to insert into a table you own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you misunderstood the question, but I know that I'm not sure whether you wrote the whole question.

Privileges you granted are related to access to SYS-owned objects, and I really can't tell whether that's what you should do.

From my point of view, you should stick to **object privileges**, i.e. grant what you specified on your own objects to that role. For example (created in my 11g XE database):

Grant Scott privilege to create roles:

```
SQL> connect sys/pwd@xe as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant create role to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Create a role and grant certain privileges to it:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create role univuser identified by univuser;

Role created.

SQL> grant select, update, insert, delete on emp to univuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is begin null; end;
  2  /

Procedure created.

SQL> grant execute on p_test to univuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create sequence seq_test;

Sequence created.

SQL> grant select on seq_test to univuser;

Grant succeeded.
```

List of privileges UNIVUSER has:

```
SQL> select table_name, privilege from role_tab_privs where role = 'UNIVUSER';

TABLE_NAME                     PRIVILEGE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
EMP                            DELETE
EMP                            INSERT
EMP                            UPDATE
EMP                            SELECT
P_TEST                         EXECUTE
SEQ_TEST                       SELECT

6 rows selected.
```

Now, grant that role to another user in my database:

```
SQL> grant univuser to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Let's see whether Mike can (or can not) do something with Scott's objects; don't forget to `SET ROLE`:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> set role univuser identified by univuser;

Role set.

SQL> select count(*) from scott.emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        12

SQL> select scott.seq_test.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL> exec scott.p_test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.

**[EDIT: write SQL that writes SQL]**

```
SQL> select 'grant select, insert, update, delete on ' || table_name || ' to univuser;'
  2  from user_tables;

'GRANTSELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETEON'||TABLE_NAME||'TOunivuser;'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
grant select, insert, update, delete on EMP to univuser;
grant select, insert, update, delete on BONUS to univuser;
grant select, insert, update, delete on SALGRADE to univuser;
grant select, insert, update, delete on DEPT to univuser;

SQL>

SQL> select 'grant execute on ' || object_name || ' to univuser;'
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'SEQUENCE');

'GRANTEXECUTEON'||OBJECT_NAME||'TOUNIVUSER;'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
grant execute on EMPTY_TABLE to univuser;
grant execute on SIEROT to univuser;
grant execute on P_RC to univuser;
grant execute on F_RC to univuser;
grant execute on MYFUNCTION to univuser;
grant execute on F_RET to univuser;
grant execute on F_REGNUM to univuser;
grant execute on F_COUNT_OF_SUNDAYS to univuser;
grant execute on P_TEST to univuser;
grant execute on F_TEST to univuser;
grant execute on MTJ_ID_SEQ to univuser;
```

Comment: thank you that was very helpful but i need to create a table named temp?
I want to give this privilege to all tables is that possible ?

Comment: You're welcome. Nope - don't create any additional tables. My example used EMP table (which belongs to Scott's schema) - you'd grant privileges on your own tables. Unfortunately, there's no *single command* which would make that possible, so you'll have to grant privileges to each table separately. In order not to do that manually, write SQL that creates SQL for you. I edited my answer, have a look.

Comment: I used the command `ALTER USER  user_name QUOTA 100M ON USERS` and it allowed me to insert in the tables.